# How to group permissions from a Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I have Role objects with permissions (JSONB objects).
A User object can be assigned to many Roles.

The Role object looks like this:

```
<Role id: 235134714, account_id: 1, title: "Admin", permissions: {"task_create"=>true}>
```

I am looking for a way to extract all permissions (into an array) from all Role objects that a User is assigned to. The criteria for a successful extraction is the following:

1. Each permission should only be show once in the resulting array.
2. The value "true" should always be selected over "false" if there are two Roles that got the same permission but one of them are false but one or more is true.

This is my code right now (which is missing the true/false check):

```
def permissions
      perms = []
      self.roles.each do |role|
        perms << role.permissions unless perms.include?(role.permissions)
      end
      perms
    end
```

I searched high and low for a way to do this buy cannot find a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to use `each_with_object` to build a hash and then convert the hash to an array. This operator `||=` will prefer `true` over `false`.

```
permissions = self.roles.each_with_object({}) do |role, hash|
  role.permissions.each do |key, value|
    hash[key] ||= value
  end
end
permissions.map { |key, value| { key => value } }
```

Answer (score 1):

This has the [unnecessary JSON anti-pattern](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/) written all over it.

By using JSON you're forgoing all the benefits that ActiveRecord and the relational database model offers and completely de-normalizing your data. This is also a problem that's relatively easy to solve with two separate tables:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :role_permissions
  has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions
end


# rails g model permission name resource:belongs_to:polymorphic   
class Permission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :role_permissions
  has_many :roles, through: :role_permissions
  belongs_to :resource, 
    polymorphic: true,
    optional: true
end

# rails g model role_permission role:belongs_to permission:belongs_to
class RolePermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :permission
end
```

The equivalent to creating that permission would be:

```
p = Permission.find_or_create_by!(resource_type: 'Post', name: :create)
p = Permission.find_or_create_by!(resource: Post.first, name: :modify)
```

This lets you scope permissions to a class of resources or a single resource (by adding a id). And you can attach any number of permissions to a role without duplication:

```
admin = Role.create!(name: :admin)
admin.permissions.find_or_create_by!(resource_type: 'Post', name: :create)
admin.permissions.find_or_create_by!(resource_type: 'User', name: :ban)
```

Querying for permissions is simply done by querying the association:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :role_permissions
  has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions

  def has_permission?(name, resource = nil)
    if resource.nil?
      permissions.where(name: name, resource: nil)
    elsif resource.is_a?(Class)
      permissions.where(name: name, resource_type: resource, resource_id: nil)
    else
      permissions.where(name: name, resource: resource)
    end.exists?  
  end
end
```